# config init.author.name Use `--init-author-name` instead

Tags: node.js, npm

npm init -y command package.fson file creates but this warning shows everytime   config init.author.name Use `--init-author-name` instead,
i also searched for .npmrc file & opened it but file is empty no code in it.

kindly solve the problem with explaination step by step